# AngularJs input with required alphanumeric

Tags: angularjs, regex

So I have this form that has an id input field.
I want to restrict it to alpha numeric with no spaces so I set this up:

```
self.pattern = /^[a-z0-9]*$/;
```

Which is used in my view like this:

```
<input class="form-control" name="id" type="text" ng-model="controller.model.id" ng-disabled="controller.id" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9]*$/" ng-trim="" ng-maxlength="10" required />
```

But I want to modify my pattern to say that there must be at least 1 letter, but it can have 0 digits.
Can someone let me know how to do this?

Comment: Try `^[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$`

Comment: Use `ng-pattern="/^\d*[a-z][a-z\d]*$/"`, add `i` modifier if you need to also match uppercase letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*[a-z][a-z\d]*$/"
```

Add `i` modifier if you need to also match uppercase letters:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d*[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i"
```

If you need to disallow leading/trailing whitespaces add `ng-trim="false"`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `[a-z]` - a letter
- `[a-z\d]*` - 0 or more letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.